# Screen Time - How do you allow specific websites for Safari?

Tags: ipad, safari, screen-time

Most of the posts I've seen around this saying it's not possible are a couple of years old; have there been any new changes with how Screen Time works with Safari? I've been unsuccessful in finding a way to permit specific websites for my daughter's iPad, so I'm constantly getting requests for all of the different sites she needs for school that day.

I know one option is to use a different browser, but how does that affect content restrictions? Does using a browser other than Safari in any way also circumvent the protection from accessing sites that contain adult content?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to access ***Prevent web content*** in Screen Time. See my summary below or follow a step by step guide [here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-safari-parental-controls-iphone-ipad-mac-4797504).

iOS can automatically filter website content to limit access to adult content in Safari and apps on your device. You can also add specific websites to an approved or blocked list, or you can limit access to only approved websites.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings > Screen Time.
2. Tap Content & Privacy Restrictions and enter your Screen Time passcode.
3. Tap Content Restrictions, then tap Web Content.
4. Choose Unrestricted Access, Limit Adult Websites or Allowed Websites Only.

Depending on the access you allow, you may need to add information, such as the website that you want to restrict.

[image]

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201304#web-content)

Comment: How does one add subdomains under a website, for example I want to give access to everything with mit.edu or google.com?

Answer (score 1):

It's very complicated (deep in the settings menus).

**Settings** > **Screen Time** > **Content & Privacy Restrictions** > **Content Restrictions** > **Web Content**

Under **ALWAYS ALLOW** click **Add Website** then add the URL of the website you want to always allow, e.g.: "www.khanacademy.org"

Comment: How does one add subdomains under a website, for example I want to give access to everything with mit.edu or google.com?